# Determine X in the geometric problem of two circles that intersect.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

As I determine the value of X in this problem:
I have tried to look for some relationship that allows you to reach something, but I do not find where to start, I thought about the proportions in the circle but there is so little information that I do not know what to do.

Thanks in advance

EDIT
*Well, it is about calculating "x" in the figure with the information given.
There are two circles with center O and O' , a chord AD that intersects perpendicularly with the radius of the larger circle at C, also, the segment CO'=4 , ask AB=x , I hope it is clearer.*

[image: Pro]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If $r$ is the radius of the smaller circle, $r + 4 = r - 4 + x$

Comment: hi, This should be very easy, but why equal?
Don't tell me it's because the radius bisects the chord by intercepting it at 90 degrees.

Comment: @maria, we have $R^2=OC^2+(r+4)^2=OC^2+(r-4+x)^2$ which gives $r+4=r-4+x\Rightarrow r-4+x=r+4\Rightarrow x=8$, where R and r are the radii of big and small circles respectively.

Comment: Triangle $OAC$ is congruent to $ODC$, then $AD=2CD$. $CD=CO' + O'D$. $O'B=O'D$, $BD=O'B+O'D=2O'D$ Then $x=AD-BD=2CD-2O'D=$ $2(CD-O'D)=2(CO'+O'D-O'D)=2CO'=8$.